# Extern makes no difference

Tags: c

I am defining a global variable in `test2.h`

```
#ifndef TEST2_H
#define TEST2_H

int test_var;

void use_it(void);

#endif
```

and defining it again in two different files, `test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test2.h"

int test_var;

int main() {
    printf("The test_var is: %d\n", ++test_var); // prints 1
    use_it(); // prints 2
}
```

and  `test2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test2.h"

int test_var;

void use_it() {
    printf("The test_var is: %d", ++test_var);
}
```

I replaced the definition of `test_var` with `extern int test_var` and got the same result. That is, in both cases both files, `test.c` and `test2.c` have access to the global variable `test_var`. I was under the impression that without `extern`, each file would have their own copy of `test_var`. Observation suggests that this is not the case. So when does `extern` actually do something?

Comment: Don't place global variables in headers. If you want two different variables `test_var`, make them `static`, and place them in the `.c` file, not in the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You end up with two copies of `test_var` and this is undefined behavior.

> (C99, 6.9p5) "If an identifier declared with external  linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operandof a sizeof operator whose result is an integer constant),
>   somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external
>   definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one"

In your case the linker may be nice with you and merges the two symbols but this is still not portable and is undefined behavior. If you are using the GNU linker, you can use `--warn-common` to get the warning (and `--fatal-warnings` if you want an error).

To fix your issue, put the `extern` specifier in the declaration of `test_var` in the `.h` file and remove one of the definition of `test_var` (for example the one in `test.c` file).

Comment: I see, so extern is used for portability?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton no, extern for objects is used to declare without defining.

Comment: @George: `extern` is used to tell the compiler that it is defined somewhere (but it should be defined only once), but not necessarily in the source file that is currently being compiled. The linker has the task of finding out where and actually reserving space for it (loosely spoken).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, multiple definitions is undefined behavior so ideally I would want to declare once with extern and define once in the corresponding .c file. But why not just declare and define once in the .h file? e.g., int test_var = 37;

Comment: You would then have multiply defined copies of `test_var` in any .c that includes that .h.  There is a good chance your compiler would flag that for you during compile/build.  This then is one example of where using `extern` scope comes in handy.  As said:  create `extern` in a .h, then define once in a .c.  The Variable will then be available to any .c that includes that .h.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior, as others have noted, but what you are seeing here is the common extension described in appendix J.5.11 of the C99 spec, where multiple external definitions in different compilation units are allowed as long as none or only one of them are initialized and the types of all of them are the same.

In this case, with the extension, the definitions will be combined into a single definition at link time.

You also appear to be confused by the fact that the `extern` keyword, when used at the global scope, has nothing to do with extern linkage for declarations and definitions.  *ALL* declarations at the global scope have extern linkage *unless* they have a `static` or `inline` keyword.  The `extern` keyword serves to make such a declaration *just* a declaration.  Without the `extern` keyword a global variable declaration is also a definition, and that is the only effect of the `extern` keyword in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same variable declared in 2 diferent files as `int test_var` for example:

file1.c

```
int test_var;
```

file2.c

```
int test_var;
```

both variables will have their own memory adress, so they are two diferent variables with the same name.

if you have, two variables declared in 2 diferent files declared as `extern int test_var`, for example:

file1.c

```
extern int test_var; //this is a mistake
```

file2.c

```
extern int test_var; //this is a mistake
```

the compiler will return an error when you try to do something with that variables because with the keyword `extern`you are not reserving any space for that variable, you only use that keyword to say that a variable is already  defined (commonly in another file).

The point is to unsderstand that a global variable is defined once with a sentence like `int test_var` (when you define a variable the compiler reserve space for it) and it's declared in every other file that need access to it with `extern int test_var` (when you declare a variable with the extern keyword you saying the compiler that variable is already defined and you want to have access to it in the file you are declaring it).

So an example of how to use a global variable wil be:

file1.c

```
int test_var; //definition

void useit(void);

int main () {
    test_var=7;
    useit();
    return 0;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void useit (void) {

    extern int test_var; //declaration
    printf ("the variable value is %d",test_var);
}
```

Comment: +1.  But I think your comment, `"...the compiler will return an error..."` is incorrect.  The file will compile but the linker will fail if `test_var` has not been declared somewhere that the file `extern`ing it has access to.

Comment: I think you mean defined, in that case, yes, you are right, I wasn't clear enought because my english.

Comment: Yes, define, not declare.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

`extern int test_var;` is a *declaration*. This announces that "Somewhere, there should exist `test_var` . We don't know where that is yet, but by the time we finish compiling and linking, we will find it in exactly one place".

So there has to be exactly one *definition* to match. A definition serves as a declaration, *and* also says "Here is the storage for `test_var`".

Also, `test_var` could either have *internal linkage* or *external linkage*.  The default behaviour is external linkage. If you provide more than one definition for a variable of external linkage, it is undefined behaviour.

Internal linkage is indicated by including `static` in the declaration. You can have as many definitions as you want of a static variable (so long as only one per file has an initializer).

Summing up, we have:

```
extern int test_var;    // declaration, external linkage
static int test_var;    // declaration, definition, internal linkage
int test_var;           // declaration, definition, external linkage
```

Note: the last two cases are actually *tentative definitions*: this is a thing that C has but C++ doesn't; the way it works is that it behaves like a declaration at first; but then , for each unit, if there is no later definition then this actually serves as a definition.

So you can write in C:

```
int test_var;
// stuff
int test_var = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gcc` and possibly some other compilers, you just stumbled upon some Unix tradition. Namely that uninitialized global variables are placed in the common block where multiple definitions of the same variable are merged during linking.

`gcc` can be told to put uninitialized global variables into the data section with the option `-fno-common`. With this, the linker will report an error when there are multiple definitions of the same variable name.